# Load html from returned string

Tags: html, asp.net, code-behind

I have the string and its returning function in the code-behind:

```
string xmlContents = "<ul><li>Installation<br /><ul><li>Startup</li><li>Getting there</li><li>Steps</li>" +
                    "<li>Pictures</li></ul></li><li>Usage<br /><ul><li>Tilbud pane</li><li>Report pane</li>" +
                "</ul></li></ul>";
public String returnXml()
    {
        return xmlContents;
    }
```

Then I call it in the aspx file:

```
<div id="treeviewMenu">
    <%returnXml(); %>
</div>
```

When I simply write the html code (of the list) directly in the div - it's ok. But by passing the string - it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

**Note: = sign whithout ; sign**

Replace with this code:

```
<div id="treeviewMenu">
   <%=returnXml() %>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily assign html to div by making `div` server accessible by adding runat="server"

*HTML*

```
<div id="treeviewMenu" runat="server"></div>
```

*In code behind*

```
treeviewMenu.InnerHTML = xmlContents;
```

Comment: when I add the `=` sign in `<%= returnXml(); %>` I get exceptions. Otherwise it runs. 
And where am I supposed to put the `treeviewMenu.InnerHTML = xmlContents;` in the code behind, as I get exceptions if I put it in the function that I have. If I put it separately, the compiler is unhappy. And overall, what's the point of the function returning the string, if I use this `treeviewMenu.InnerHTML =...` ?

Comment: I made it work just by using the `treeviewMenu.InnerHTML=....` in the `Page_Load()` and removing the code blocks in the div, because I was getting the exception `The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).`

Comment: I would do that way too.